# How do you upload a package to PyPI using Windows CMD?

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos

I am a beginner in Python and I own a book on Python, but I'm stuck on a part where you have to upload a package to PyPI. The book shows how to do it with Mac and Linux, but not Windows.
I've tried to follow the book, but it simply doesn't work with Windows CMD. I was wondering if somebody could help me on this topic. Any help would be appreciated!

-- Thanks=) !!!

Comment: What do your windows commands look like, that you have tried? And show the errors. Should be pretty much the same.

Comment: If you are just testing out uploading to PyPI *please* use the [PyPI test site](http://testpypi.python.org/pypi)! It's exactly the same as the main PyPI in terms of function, but it doesn't pollute the main package index with dummy packages, etc.

Comment: Well, my Windows commands look like this: C:\Users\(My name)>setup.py register  And then it says... 'setup.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed Python using the windows installer? It sounds like the Python scripts aren't registered with the python runtime.

You can also do

```
> cd C:\Path\To\The\Package\Directory
C:\Path\To\The\Package\Directory> C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py register
```

(replacing Python27 with the version you have installed).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work because it said: C:\Python32\python.exe: Can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory =( It probably thinks that setup.py is a file, but it's not! Oh well, I might just have to install Cygwin, mabye that will help...

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I can't rate your comment as much as I'd like to, because, I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: You need to be in the same directory as `setup.py`, or you can specify the path. I've updated my post with that.

Comment: I think  that might be it! I'll need to try that though, thanks =)

Comment: Well, It sort of worked and it sort of didn't. What I mean is that it showed the options and all, but the name I used for my package was already in use, so I renamed my package and I tried the same codes again, it didn't work! So I was so frustrated, stressed and clueless, I just hope you would have a solution for me so I can upload my package to Python successfully ;(